# Electric field between parallel plates of capacitor

Tags: capacitor

At school I have this exercise to solve:

*Compute the modulus of the electric field between the (parallel) plates of a capacitor in air having plate distance d=10nm , plate area 1um^2, applied voltage of 2V.
If the dielectric is SiO2, find the corresponding displacement electric field.*

I have done the following calculations, I would like your opinion on the unfolding. Is it correct?
[image]

Comment: Since the *electric modulus* is the reciprocal of dielectric permittivity, you might prefer to clarify your question in this way. Electronic engineers tend to use use and understand `permittivity`. They don't much use `electric modulus`. +1, regardless.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So I guess the calculations I made are correct. Right?